# Automatically/Dynamically Create Links to All Files in a Folder?

Tags: hyperlink, libraries

I have 45gb of videos and accompanying PowerPoint docs in a folder on our network that I want to make available through our SharePoint site. The videos themselves are 250mb WMVs. From what I've read, files this size really shouldn't be uploaded into SharePoint.

Is there a way to tell SharePoint to look at a folder and create links to every file in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to utilize a third-party solution for this (i.e., Bamboo Solutions), which will allow you to add their web part to a page which will give you a "windows explorer" feel to the desired file server.  I have never used on of these, but that is the path available for you.

Comment: AvePoint Connector also works for something like this. You can point it at a network share and leave the content there, but it is revealed through SharePoint as if it was a library. There are two I think, one for media files, which is probably what you would want more for this since they are videos and one for regular documents.

Comment: I had a feeling it was not an 'out of the box' solution. Thanks for including a vendor (you too @Lori)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement your [custom BDC](http://code.dortikum.net/2011/01/14/custom-bdc-connector-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1/) in [VS2010](http://vimeo.com/7874711).

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a solution that can be helpful for you. [It is a Remote BLOB Storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx)